# Is there a way to enable full read/write for a hfs+ hdd? (x noob)

Tags: filesystem

is there a way to enable full read/write for a journaled hfs+ hdd? (x noob, laptop, can't backup/convert fs/reformat)

Comment: I doubt is it possible. Full speed is on non journaled

Comment: Sorry, I meant get permissions/priveledges )

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/90339/how-do-i-set-read-write-permissions-my-hard-drives